# OCaml: Insert integer into sorted list of integers

Tags: list, insert, functional-programming, ocaml

What is an efficient way in OCaml to write a function `insert : int -> list -> list` that will insert an int into a sorted list of int and return the new list?

This is what i have so far to append to the end of a list:

```
let insert x list =
 match list with
  [] -> [x]
  | list :: t -> list :: (insert t x)
```

Comment: You need to do more work on your question if you want a useful answer. The best is probably to show some code you wrote, and to explain what seems to be wrong with it. Something to think about: what would the code look like if you knew the new int was smaller than the first element of the sorted list?

Answer (score 3):

Since I asked for code, I guess I should give you some feedback :-)

Your code has roughly the right form for a recursive solution to the problem. The biggest problems I see are:

- Nowhere do you compare your new number x to any of the values in the list. So there's no way you can be sure your returned list is sorted.
- Your recursive call to `insert` has the arguments in the wrong order.

A smaller problem:

- You need to say `let rec insert ...` to define a recursive function.

You probably want to think about 3 cases, rather than the 2 you have here:

1. List is empty
2. New value is less than or equal to the beginning of the list
3. New value is greater than the beginning of the list

I hope this helps.